# fetch batch translate job details using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, translate

I was trying to find the LanguagePair and Operation associated with a given AWS translate job using the JAVA SDK.

Using the AWS web console, i created a couple of batch jobs to translate a few english sentences to french. In CloudWatch, i could see the metric dimensions as

LanguagePair: en-fr
Operation: TranslateText

Can i retrieve the same information (LanguagePair and Operation) for a given job,
using the TranslateAsyncClient.describeTextTranslationJob(...) method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **TranslateClient** to describes a translation job given the job number as input. This uses the **TranslateClient**; however you can use the Async version as well.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.translate.TranslateClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.translate.model.DescribeTextTranslationJobRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.translate.model.DescribeTextTranslationJobResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.translate.model.TranslateException;
// snippet-end:[translate.java2._describe_jobs.import]

/**
 * To run this Java V2 code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class DescribeTextTranslationJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    DescribeTextTranslationJob <id> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    id - a translation job ID value. You can obtain this value from the BatchTranslation example.\n";

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String id = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        TranslateClient translateClient = TranslateClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        describeTextTranslationJob(translateClient, id);
        translateClient.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[translate.java2._describe_jobs.main]
    public static void describeTextTranslationJob(TranslateClient translateClient, String id) {

      try {

        DescribeTextTranslationJobRequest textTranslationJobRequest = DescribeTextTranslationJobRequest.builder()
                .jobId(id)
                 .build();

        DescribeTextTranslationJobResponse jobResponse = translateClient.describeTextTranslationJob(textTranslationJobRequest);
        System.out.println("The job status is "+jobResponse.textTranslationJobProperties().jobStatus());
        System.out.println("The source language is "+jobResponse.textTranslationJobProperties().sourceLanguageCode());
        System.out.println("The target language is "+jobResponse.textTranslationJobProperties().targetLanguageCodes());
    
      } catch (TranslateException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          System.exit(1);
      }
        // snippet-end:[translate.java2._describe_jobs.main]
   }
}
```

To see all the data you can get back using this code, see this JavaDoc - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/translate/model/TextTranslationJobProperties.html